# How do I make and apply a Normal Map?

Tags: texturing, uv, normals

I'm having problems trying to make a Normal map. Essentially I want the High Res model detail to go on to the Lower Res one. And that's done trough Normal Maps correct?

Here is the blend file:

https://mega.nz/#!EQ11RYgR!kwZ57m9rj-nQx7dTKSlOfLcM_4eOlhTOR1GBoLvCmDQ

I managed to go this far, but the texture doesn't look quite there. It looks pixalated in some places, and the effect ain't showing on the Low Res model either.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to BSE! This question looks like it might be a duplicate of either http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32865/strange-artifacts-in-normal-map?rq=1 or possibly http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38555/normal-map-looking-weird-on-mesh?rq=1 both of which have good, but unaccepted answers. Because StackExchange is a repository of answers (not a forum), we like to avoid duplicating answers. If your question is different from these, please reword it so that the community can be more helpful. Images of the problem you're experiencing would certainly be helpful.

Comment: It looks like you dont have any textures on either one.
One simply has more faces than the other....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ray distance

You should increase your baking ray distance in order to capture the whole highpoly surface. Here's a comparison between different values (0 on the left, 0.1 on the right),

[image]

As said in the [manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html#additional-options), the parameter controls

> [...] how far a point on another object can be away from the point on the active object. Only needed for Selected to Active.

Low margin settings helps us to see how some parts are missing in the image on the left. Once naked correctly dont' forget to set "non color data" and to connect to the vector socket in the shader.

[image]

Notice how the wrinkles and other detais are correctly transferred upon the low-poly mesh.

Answer (score 0):

For making a normal map from diffuse textures, I would use CrazyBump. For an in-depth guide on texturing and using maps on models, here's a really good tutorial video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W07H7xeUnGE